# How to use a custom component in a ModalPage Ionic 6/Capacitor?

Tags: javascript, android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a floating button in a custom component so I can reuse this component in several pages. When I inject this component into a page this works. But when I use this component in a modal then I get an error. This is my code for my float button.

**Fabbutton.component.html**

```
<div class="fixed">
  <ion-fab (click)="scrollToTop()" vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" edge slot="fixed">
    <ion-fab-button class="toolbar-color" size="small">
      <ion-icon name="arrow-up"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
  </ion-fab>
</div>
```

**Fabbutton.component.css**

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 85px;
    right: 0;
}
```

**Fabbutton.component.ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fabbutton',
  templateUrl: './fabbutton.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fabbutton.component.scss'],
})
export class FabbuttonComponent {
  
  @Output('onClick') onClick = new EventEmitter<any>();

  scrollToTop() {
   this.onClick.emit();
  }
}
```

In the modal page I use this component like this:

**ListModal.page.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar class="toolbar-color">
    <ion-title>{{name}}</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-button (click)="modalCtrl.dismiss()">
        <ion-icon name="arrow-back-sharp" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content class="ion-padding">
  <app-fabbutton (onClick)="scrollToTop()"></app-fabbutton>
</ion-content>
```

**ListModal.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ListModalPageRoutingModule } from './listmodal-routing.module';
import { ListModalPage } from './listmodal.page';
import { FabbuttonComponent } from 'src/app/components/fabbutton/fabbutton.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    ListModalPageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [ListModalPage, FabbuttonComponent]
})
export class ListModalPageModule {}
```

I use this same proces for the pages and this works. But When I use this in a Modal I get the following error:

> core.mjs:7626 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type
> FabbuttonComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules:
> ListmodalPageModule and RecipesPageModule! Please consider moving
> FabbuttonComponent to a higher module that imports ListmodalPageModule
> and RecipesPageModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports
> and includes FabbuttonComponent then import that NgModule in
> ListmodalPageModule and RecipesPageModule.
>
> Error: Type FabbuttonComponent is part of the declarations of 2
> modules: ListmodalPageModule and RecipesPageModule! Please consider
> moving FabbuttonComponent to a higher module that imports
> ListmodalPageModule and RecipesPageModule. You can also create a new
> NgModule that exports and includes FabbuttonComponent then import that
> NgModule in ListmodalPageModule and RecipesPageModule.
>
> ```
> at verifySemanticsOfNgModuleDef (core.mjs:24393:15) 
>
> at RecipesPageModule.get (core.mjs:24313:21) 
>
> at getInjectorDef (core.mjs:482:13) 
>
> at walkProviderTree (core.mjs:6473:18) 
>
> at core.mjs:6433:13 
>
> at core.mjs:4193:76 
>
> at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) 
>
> at deepForEach (core.mjs:4193:11) 
>
> at core.mjs:4193:51 
>
> at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) 
>
> at resolvePromise (zone.js:1262:35) 
>
> at resolvePromise (zone.js:1216:21) 
>
> at zone.js:1329:21 
>
> at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:443:35) 
>
> at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:26339:33) 
>
> at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:442:64) 
>
> at Zone.runTask (zone.js:214:51) 
>
> at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:632:39)
> ```

I have tried the following links to fix my error:

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-create-a-reusable-modal-dialog-component-in-angular-8-241cc738d260

https://medium.com/@mohamed_larbi.chouaiar/how-to-build-your-angular-components-and-use-it-everywhere-72dea7ecc0d6

Why can I use my Fabbutton component in my pages but not in the modal page?

How can I use the Fabbutton component in my modal page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if i understand correctly, the problem is you try to use a component in multiple modules (in ionic every page is a module).
Angular not allow you to do that directly.

You have do create a module that export the components you have to use.

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FabbuttonComponent } from 'src/app/components/fabbutton/fabbutton.component';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [ CommonModule ],
    declarations: [ FabbuttonComponent ],
    exports:      [ FabbuttonComponent, CommonModule, FormsModule ]
})
export class FabbuttonSharedMobule { }
```

Now import that module where you need the component.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ListModalPageRoutingModule } from './listmodal-routing.module';
import { ListModalPage } from './listmodal.page';
import { FabbuttonSharedModule } from 'src/app/common/fabbuttonshared.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    FabbuttonSharedModule,
    IonicModule,
    ListModalPageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [ListModalPage]
})
export class ListModalPageModule {}
```

[Check this](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules)